# Zurb Ink Button Not Respecting 2 Columns in Panel

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, html-email, zurb-ink

In creating a HTML email, I am using Zurb Ink framework.

I have a panel that I want to have a several horizontal lines of display inside of the panel. For instance:

```
Panel:
[assigned] 12/12/2013 12:14:00 Reboot Server
[unassigned] 12/12/2013 15:00:00 Shutdown Server
```

Where there is a button for assigned/unassigned and text following.

In this code I have I created the panel and the button successfully inside the panel. However, I can not get the button to take only two columns. How can I make the button take only 2 columns and then have text after the button?

```
            <table class="row callout">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="twelve columns">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="panel" style="background: #ECF8FF; border-color: #b9e5ff">
                                    <table class="two columns">
                                        <table class="tiny-button small radius alert">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    unassigned
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Your "two-columns" table has no `<tr>` or `<td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe sub-columns are what you're looking for. From the Zurb documentation:

> While the Ink grid can't be nested like its Foundation counterpart, Ink does provide a nestable sub-grid for when one grid just isn't enough. By applying a .sub-columns class (as well as a numbered class, same as the primary grid) to a  tag underneath a .columns table, you can sub-divide the .columns table into sub-columns.

**Markup**

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td>

            <table class="row">
                <tr>
                    <td class="wrapper">

                        <table class="twelve columns">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="four sub-columns">
                                    <table class="button">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <a href="#">Assigned</a>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class="eight sub-columns last">2/12/2013 12:14:00 Reboot Server</td>
                                <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="four sub-columns">
                                    <table class="button">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td> <a href="#">Unassigned</a>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class="eight sub-columns last">12/12/2013 15:00:00 Shutdown Server</td>
                                <td class="expander"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/MPQ38/1/

Comment: No, he is searching for table inside "panel" class not just sub-columns

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> To create buttons that look great in most clients, make a table of
>   class `button` to wrap your `<a>` tag. Buttons expand to the full width of
>   their container by default, so if you don't want them to expand all
>   the way, consider placing them in a sub-grid or block-grid element.

It means you can put the button table inside a sub-grid element