# Zurb Ink email - sub-grid button without content on right?

Tags: html, css, email, zurb-ink

I am working on an email where I have a button underneath some text, with an image of a product to the right.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/uw4Xz/

```
<body style="background:#cccccc">
 <table class="body" style="background:#cccccc">
    <tr>
         <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
             <center>
                <table class="container">
                    <tr>
                        <td><!-- BEGIN CONTAINER TD-->
                            <table class="row">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="wrapper last">
                                        <table class="twelve columns white">
                                            <tr style="border-bottom:5px solid #ffc780">
                                                <td bgcolor="#557dae">
                                                    <table align="right">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/236×94" alt="">
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="expander"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="row white">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="wrapper last">
                                        <table class="twelve columns">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-pad">
                                                    <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet aptent taciti sociosqu</h6>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <table class="row white">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="wrapper last">
                                        <table class="twelve columns">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text-pad">
                                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia nunc id diam bibendum tincidunt eu vel nisi.</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                            
                            <table class="row white">
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="wrapper">
                                    <table class="eight columns">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-pad">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia nunc id diam bibendum tincidunt eu vel nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia nunc id diam bibendum tincidunt eu vel nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="expander"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text-pad">
                                            <table class="button">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a href="#">Order Now</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>


                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td class="wrapper last">
                                <table class="four columns">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="text-pad">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/144x186" style="border:1px solid #444444"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="expander"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>

                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                          </table>
```

I found an answer on here that confirms my suspicion that a sub-grid needs to be used:

[Zurb Ink Button Not Respecting 2 Columns in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100964/zurb-ink-button-not-respecting-2-columns-in-panel)

That example however has text to the right of the button. I'd like my button to be half its current width, but with no text to the right of it. The paragraph above the button should remain as wide as it is.

I hope that's clear!

Answer (score 0):

In your case the simplest solution is going to be setting the width of the button to 50%.

Something similar to this will work:

```
.button {
  width:50% !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .button {
    width:100% !important;
  }

}
```

Here's the working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/u3msA/)**.